# MySQL LIKE %string% not quite forgiving enough. Anything else I can use?

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I've got a client who's asking if their search, which searches for company names which could be searched for in several formats depending on user input, such as the company stored in the database being A J R Kelly Ltd for instance,  If a user searches "A J R Kelly" it's found, using;

```
<cfif pctermsCount gt 0>
AND (LOWER(p.name)  LIKE '%#pcTerms#%')
</cfif>
```

If they search for "Kelly" the company is found, but if they search for a broken version of the string like "A J Kelly" or "AJ Kelly" it's not found.

Is there anything I can do to make it just a little bit more forgiving?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using MyISAM, you can use full text indexing. [See this tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304)

If you're using a different storage engine, you could use a third party full text engine like sphinx, which can act as a [storage engine for mysql](http://sphinxsearch.com/index.html) or a separate server that can be queried.

With MySQL full text indexing a search on `A J Kelly` would match `AJ Kelly` (no to confuse matters but A, J and AJ would be ignored as they are too short by default and it would match on Kelly.) Generally Fulltext is much more forgiving (and usually faster than LIKE '%string%') because allows partial matches which can then be ranked on relevance.

You can also use [SOUNDEX](http://www.madirish.net/node/85) to make searches more forgiving by indexing the phonetic equivalents of words and search them by applying SOUNDEX on your search terms and then using those to search the index.  With soundex `mary`, `marie`, and `marry` will all match, for example.

Comment: We are using MyISAM. I did consider FullText so I tested to make sure I can enable that on the table, it can. I've not tried it yet, because it'd mean quite a bit of fiddling to give it a go on the user interface, but I'll show a few examples to the client in PHPMyAdmin, but I've got a feeling FullText might be a bit too forgiving for his liking. Thanks for your answer. Fulltext seems to be the best solution if he can't live with the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't need any fiddling on the UI. You could take the same search string and change the WHERE to something like `where MATCH (indexcol) against ('A J Kelly' in Boolean Mode) ORDER BY MATCH (indexcol) against ('A J Kelly' in Boolean Mode) DESC`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was unclear. By "user interface" I meant the website itself's backend code, there's quite a lot of query building based on lots of stuff coming from lots of places, it's quite overcomplex, so it's easier to test if he likes the results from fulltext by showing him in PHPMyAdmin than making lots of changes to the backend code to try it out. Sorry, but thanks for posting that query snippet, saved me more time. :D

Answer (score 4):

If you are indeed running ColdFusion, you have access to CF's full text indexing using either [Verity](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7b7e.html) or [Solr/Lucene](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS2B335964-A0DA-4add-B9FE-4041464EC9E1.html). Either of those should give you good "fuzzy matching" capability for strings.

Having to use MyISAM tables is a bitter pill just for full-text indexing - you give up a lot of peace of mind, and things like Foreign Key constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new column and make it the searchable version of the name by removing the whitespace, then set the column datatype as FULLTEXT (will only work with MyISAM). You may want to look into Lucene/SOLR as well. SOLR provides a number of tokenizers which work very well in this type of situation. Learning curve is fairly high, but worth it in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky, i suppose a simple method would be to remove whitespaces on database term searching, so AJRKelly is used instead of A J R Kelly.  Then use whitespace as a seperator for individual search terms.  That way A J Kelly would search for A, J and Kelly seperately.  AJ Kelly would search for AJ and Kelly seperately.  They would match on the AJRKelly whitespace removed database term.

Comment: This really only covers a narrow use case, only allows exact matches, and would be difficult to implement efficiently. Either there would be two columns for every column to search (one with, one without spaces) or whitespace would be stripped out prior do performing the like (which will get very expensive)