# Searching a database with forgiveness.

Tags: php, sql, search

I have a database of 30k elements, each game names.

I'm currently using:

```
SELECT * from gamelist WHERE name LIKE '%%%$search%%%' OR aliases LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 10"
```

for the searchbar.
However, it can get really picky about things like:

```
'Animal Crossing: Wild World'
```

See, many users won't know that ':' is in that phrase, so when they start searching:

```
 Animal Crossing Wild World
```

It won't show up.

How can I have the sql be more forgiving?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL LIKE %string% not quite forgiving enough. Anything else I can use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940346/mysql-like-string-not-quite-forgiving-enough-anything-else-i-can-use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the non alphanumeric characters in the search parameter with wildcards so `Animal Crossing Wild World` becomes `%Animal%Crossing%Wild%World%` and filter on that.

Comment: I think this is more the solution I knew I needed, I'm just trying to find the best way to do this.

Comment: The other solution regarding fulltext may have been a better idea, but I think this answer more accurately solves my particular issue, also is a very easy fix:
`preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '%', $search);`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you make another table witch contains keyworks like

```
+---------+------------+
| game_id | keyword_id |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |          1 |
|       1 |          2 |
|       1 |          3 |
|       1 |          4 |
+---------+------------+
```

```
+------------+--------------+
| keyword_id | keyword_name |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | animal       |
|          2 | crossing     |
|          3 | wild         |
|          4 | world        |
+------------+--------------+
```

After that you can easily explode the user given text into keywords and search for them in the database, witch will give you the id's of the possible games he/she was looking for.

Oh, and remove special symbols, like ":" or "-", so you don't need multiple keywords for the same phrase.

Comment: this idea is good but you will end up with the same keyword multiple times: one for each matching game_id. Perhaps a table for the keywords: `Keyword(keyword_id, keyword)` and a table that makes the matches: `GameKeyword(game_id, keyword_id)`

Comment: True, changed the answer to your idea.

Answer (score 1):

The following is from [MySQL LIKE %string% not quite forgiving enough. Anything else I can use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940346/mysql-like-string-not-quite-forgiving-enough-anything-else-i-can-use) by the user M_M:

> If you're using MyISAM, you can use full text indexing. [See this tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304)
>
> If you're using a different storage engine, you could use a third party full text engine like sphinx, which can act as a [storage engine for mysql](http://sphinxsearch.com/index.html) or a separate server that can be queried.
>
> With MySQL full text indexing a search on `A J Kelly` would match `AJ Kelly` (no to confuse matters but A, J and AJ would be ignored as they are too short by default and it would match on Kelly.) Generally Fulltext is much more forgiving (and usually faster than LIKE '%string%') because allows partial matches which can then be ranked on relevance.
>
> You can also use [SOUNDEX](http://www.madirish.net/node/85) to make searches more forgiving by indexing the phonetic equivalents of words and search them by applying SOUNDEX on your search terms and then using those to search the index.  With soundex `mary`, `marie`, and `marry` will all match, for example.

Comment: I have used SOUNDEX before, but those results also do not yield proper results. Unless I'm using it wrong: 

`SELECT * from gamelist WHERE SOUNDEX(name) = SOUNDEX('%%%$search%%%') OR SOUNDEX(aliases) = SOUNDEX('%$search%') LIMIT 10`

Comment: I'm afraid I've never actually used SOUNDEX before (as said in my answer, that quote is from the user M_M), so I can't verify the validity of your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Match () AGAINST () if your MySQL engine is MyISAM or InnoDB:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Your resulting SQL will be like this:

```
SELECT * from gamelist WHERE MATCH (name, aliases) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10
```

The behavior of the search is more like the boolean search used in search engines.

Comment: I'm not using FullText for these tables.

Comment: @Adola If you happen to be using MyISAM, you actually don't need a fulltext index to use the IN BOOLEAN MODE search. Unfortunately, InnoDB requires it.